# Transfering (adding) bone weight from one bone to another

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I want to port a character from game Cyberpunk 2077 into Garry's Mod (Source engine). Model came in FBX format and I managed to export it as smd (which is needed for Source engine), and upscaled it to be the same size as other models.
Now it's time to reduce bone count. Smd allows up to 128 bones only and model comes with roughly 480 bones. I'll have to remove about 360 of them to keep the limits. It has a lot of bones, e.g. for clothes, hair, or even separate muscles that are totally useless for me. However after deleting some of them I've got unassigned vertices. And here's my question. Is there any option to add weights of one bone to another bone? I don't want to replace weights, just add them. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDeF0.png The green circle shows the bone I must keep, named RightLeg, and red circles indicate unecessary bones I want to remove. And after removing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbgPt.png, the red circle shows unassigned vertices. I can paint everything myself, but this will take ages and result might be poor. If anyone can help I will appreciate anything.

Comment: You can use the vertex weight mix modifier to add weights from one group to another group.  But for several hundred iterations, you should probably be thinking about scripting, it's not going to be much fun otherwise.

Comment: Gonna give it a try tonight, thanks for the reply! Anything is better than painting manually. And about script, well, I'm not even an intermediate in Blender, I know how couple of things work, but scripts are far beoynd my competence :)

Comment: I finally had some time to test it out! And yes, the option is exactly what I needed! Process might be slow due to the ammount of bones but I'm happy with the result. I removed quickly 6 bones with adding their wieght and it works like a charm. Thank you so much!